# Google Sign-In for server-side apps using .net

Tags: google-api

I have managed to establish a login screen using Javascript google API as described in https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow. using the function: `auth2.grantOfflineAccess()`

The API returns the following authorization code:

```
{"code":"4/yU4cQZTMnnMtetyFcIWNItG32eKxxxgXXX-Z4yyJJJo.4qHskT-UtugceFc0ZRONyF4z7U4UmAI"}
```

How do I exchange the authorization code to access token and a refresh token in an ASP.NET server?

Comment: Have you considered using the google .net client library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a server-side code for for google sign in:

```
UserCredential credential;

string[] scopes = new string[] {
    YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload
};

IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
{
    ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
    {
        ClientId = "<CLIENT-ID>",
        ClientSecret = "<CLIENT-SECRET>"
    },
    Scopes = scopes,
    DataStore = new FileDataStore("Store")
});

TokenResponse token = flow.ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync(videoUploadOptions.userId, videoUploadOptions.authorizationCode, videoUploadOptions.baseUrl, CancellationToken.None).Result;

credential = new UserCredential(flow, Environment.UserName, token);
```

The auth2 google response will be stored at the `token` object. the variable transferred from the client are: `videoUploadOptions.userId`, `videoUploadOptions.authorizationCode` and `videoUploadOptions.baseUrl`.

All the credentials will be stored at the `credential` object.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to post it back to google to get an access token and a refresh token.

```
POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
code={CODE}&client_id={ClientId}&client_secret={ClientSecret}&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code
```